# Contact from PHP doesnt work

Tags: php, html, forms

Whats the problem in here? Why it doesnt work. In HTML page button sends in here.Whenever I try to send , always works else section.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
    $to="mail@mail.com";
    $subject="Form to email message";
    $name=$_POST["user_name"];
    $mail=$_POST["user_mail"];
    $message=$_POST["user_message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $name\nEmail: $mail\n\n$message";

    mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $name <$mail>");
    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";

}
else{
        echo "Upps!Something happened.";
    }

?>
```

Here is the html page.I tried with changing name of the button.But didnt work at all.

mainpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainpage.css">


</head>
<body>

<h2><b><center>About Me</center></b></h2>

<form action="send.php" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" >
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="mail" name="user_mail">
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="msg">Message:</label>
        <textarea id="msg" name="user_message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="button">
        <input type="submit" value="Send your message">

    </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: add html here please'

Comment: We have to take a look on the submit form's html code

Comment: I'm willing to bet that the button's(or whatever it is) name is not `submit`.

Comment: kindly check your method in <form> tag. form method must be method="post". If your <form> method is GET then it will not work.

Comment: Adding to other comments, if you are running it to localhost, mail will not go. you have to do some stuff for that

Comment: Hello, can you add your html code please. I'm looking for an input element name "submit" in your form. It seems like in your condition your looking for "submit" if it is not present then your PHP condition will always end up in your "else" block. :)

Comment: i just added html code at the top

Answer (score 1):

EDITED:

Given you have provided no HTML (yet) I have done a bog standard one for you:

Your form needs to look like this:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user_name">
    Email: <input type="text" name="user_mail">
    <textarea name="user_message" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="submit"name="submit">
</form>
```

The PHP would be (after a minor tweak):

```
<?php

// Only process POST reqeusts.
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    // Get the form fields and remove whitespace.
    $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST["user_name"]));
    $name = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$name);
    $email = filter_var(trim($_POST["user_mail"]), FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $message = trim($_POST["user_message"]);

    // Check that data was sent to the mailer.
    if ( empty($name) OR empty($message) OR !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        // Set a 400 (bad request) response code and exit.
        http_response_code(400);
        echo "Please ensure you fill in all of the fields!";
        exit;
    }


    // admins email address
    $recipient = "mail@mail.com";

    // Set the email subject.
    $subject = "Enquiry Received From $name";

    // Build the email content.
    $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
    $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
    $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

    // Build the email headers.
    $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

    // Send the email.
    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers)) {
        // Set a 200 (okay) response code.
        http_response_code(200);
        echo "Thank You! Your message has been sent.
            ";
    } else {
        // Set a 500 (internal server error) response code.
        http_response_code(500);
        echo "Oops! Something went wrong and we couldn't send your message.";
    }

}

?>
```

Comment: Yet the OP would still end up in the else section every time…

Comment: If his form is borked then yes but if his form is okay then this would work perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, but we KNOW his form IS borked, that's why he asked in the first place (quote: "Whenever I try to send, always works else section.")

Answer (score 1):

Reasons can be many, let me put some of them:

1. 1st thing mainly **$_POST['submit']** is not set
2. Submit button in HTML file maybe having different name, meaning:

> it should be exactly same as below. Try this and submit it may work:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

3. Form you are submitting may be having tag mistakes.

as other told, please share html also. It will be easy to identify the issue.

Comment: i added html code at the top .

Comment: I tired like you said but still same else section works

Comment: ok, you are submitting on the same page right?

Comment: not exactly , I created in different pages like mainpage.html and send.php

Comment: Considering you really tried adding name="submit" to the submit button, it must work now. :-)

BTW, try print_r($_POST); in your PHP. ;-)

Comment: Yeah, i can see that you have not used **name="submit""** in the submit button. please add it will work

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have enough rep to comment so must post an answer..

As other's have stated, your submit button in the html form needs the name (name="submit").

I would also consider validating on other fields, and sanitizing input in your send.php file, eg:

```
<?php

$to="mail@mail.com";
$subject="Form to email message";

$name= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_name", FILTER_SANITIZE_TEXT);
$message= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_message", FILTER_SANITIZE_TEXT);
$mail= filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_mail", FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);


if( ! ($name === false || $message === false || $mail === false)
{
    $mailBody="Name: $name\nEmail: $mail\n\n$message";

    mail($to, $subject, $mailBody, "From: $name <$mail>");
    echo "Data has been submitted to $to!";
}
else
{
    echo "Upps!Something happened.";
}
```

This might be better because you get input validation for security but it also prevents users submitting blank forms.